# Where to report device-specific bugs to Samsung?

Tags: android, bug-tracking

I'm looking for a place to report Android bugs on Samsung devices.  The place would ideally have actual representation by Samsung developers.  Japanese forums are ok.

I have tried:
 - http://innovator.samsungmobile.com - This has a Java ME forum but the existing Android posts are unanswered.
 - http://developer.samsung.com - Points to the same content as the 1st link.
 - Calling Samsung 3rd level support to ask for a reference - they told me to use the 1st link but couldn't tell me which forum was appropriate to file bugs against Android devices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

They can solve even a device specific bug or forward it to a device manufacturer, optionally extending the CTS to cover a given case.

It's also good to let Samsung know about a bug. The best place for that seems to be their developer forum: http://developer.samsung.com/forum/en

Comment: If you file device-specific bugs here they will be closed because they are "device-specific".  Unfortunately forwarding data on to the manufacturer is as nebulous a process as reporting an API implementation bug through Samsung's 800#.  Meaning, I don't really know if my message was passed on reliably and I'll never hear back from anyone - I need actual representation by the developers.  Example of the bug I filed: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14360&can=1&q=FLASH_MODE_TORCH

Comment: After more consideration, I think this is as good as it is ever going to get with Samsung.

Comment: This is incorrect, google does not forward any bugs to Samsung. It is just closed as device specific, and "heavily modified version of android on their phones".

Comment: Reporting bugs to AOSP is a waste of time, since they close many bugs as "wrong forum", even bug reports specifically about open source Android code, never mind Samsung bugs.

Answer (score 4):

Answer may be obsolete - there is a [developer forum](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/) on Samsung devs website and it looks like Samsung people provide actual help.