# Android flashlight

Tags: android, hardware

I'd like to make a flashlight app like the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503480/use-camera-flashlight-in-android) for my Nexus S since all of the ones available in the Android Market require unnecessary permissions. What are the chances that this type of application can damage the hardware (led, v regulator, etc.) if I power the flash led at 100%? Should I use a 50% duty cycle (or other duty cycle) or trust the HW design?

Comment: I was unable to get the Android SDK working on my atom based netbook (surprise surprise) but I was able to finally find a free flashlight app that does not ask for any unnecessary permissions called ezLight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, I use the camera LED on my droid X all the fricken time as a flashlight.  I haven't seen any degradation.  Granted I've only had it for 6 months, but.... seems safe.

I normally dont use it for more than 15 mins at a time though.

Take that all with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I'll have to assume Samsung and Google did not try to save $0.00001 on the design and used something similar.