# Setting Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH doesn't work on Droid X 2.3

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, flashlight

I am writing an app that sets the flash mode to torch.  I have been testing the application on my Droid X, and the LED light does not come on.  I tried it on a Droid Incredible and it worked fine.  I can't figure out what the problem is.  Here is part of my code for turning on torch mode.

```
    Camera mCamera = Camera.open();
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    if(params.getFlashMode() != null){
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    }
    mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

I have added mCamera.startPreview(); because I read that should make a difference, but it doesn't.  I also made a list of available flash modes and displayed them to the screen to make sure that my Droid X does have torch mode, and it was in the list.  I even created a new application from code I found online that turns the LED flash on and off with a button.  Again it worked fine on the Droid Incredible but not the Droid X.  Is there something I am missing to get this to run on the Droid X, or could it be something with Gingerbread?  The Droid X is running Gingerbread and the Droid Incredible is running FroYo.

Answer (score 6):

There are quite a few quirks when setting FLASH_MODE_TORCH.

Often you need to start a camera preview:

```
Camera mCamera = Camera.open();
mCamera.startPreview();
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
if(params.getFlashMode() != null){
    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
}
mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

That may resolve it on some phones, other phones also require the preview to be drawn to a SurfaceView. This can be done by implementing SurfaceHolder.Callback interface in your activity.
See an example [here](http://code.google.com/p/torch/source/browse/trunk/src/com/colinmcdonough/android/torch/Torch.java).

Comment: This will crash on some front cameras that don't support TORCH. It should at least be surrounded by try catch.

Answer (score 4):

It could be that the Droid X doesn't support Torch Mode.  Try something like this:

```
        List<String> pList = camera.getParameters().getSupportedFlashModes();

        if (pList.contains(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH))
            parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);


         camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [Issue 191453](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191453):

```
SurfaceTexture mDummy = new SurfaceTexture(1); // any int argument will do
camera.setPreviewTexture(mDummy);
camera.startPreview();
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I found that works on the Droid X is the code presented by Siddhpura Amit part way down the page in this answer [Use camera flashlight in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503480/use-camera-flashlight-in-android).  He checks the manufacturer and checks to see if it contains the string "motorola."  If so, he has special code that can switch the camera Flash LED on or off.  I can verify that it does work as I have a Motorola Droid X.