# Turn ON/OFF Camera LED/flash light in Samsung Galaxy Ace 2.2.1 & Galaxy Tab

Tags: android, android-camera, galaxy, samsung-mobile, flashlight

I am turning ON Camera LED light using `FLASH_MODE_ON`.

Samsung Galaxy Ace have only three flash modes : on, off and auto.

`FLASH_MODE_TORCH` not working in Samsung Galaxy Tab & Samsung Galaxy Ace 2.2.1

Here is my code how i am turning ON my Camera LED

```
    Camera cam;
    cam = Camera.open();     
    Parameters params = cam.getParameters();
    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
    cam.setParameters(params);
    cam.startPreview();
    cam.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {
                public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                }
     });
```

And turning it off by using :

```
cam.stopPreview();
cam.release();
```

Code Reference : [Use camera flashlight in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503480/use-camera-flashlight-in-android)

But the problem is LED Light remains on just for 5sec. It just then turns OFF automatically.

Can anyone please tell where can be the problem. OR any way to turn ON the LED light continuously till its requested to Stop.

Comment: hey, did you found a solution about that problem? I'm facing the same problem and i don't find anything on internet.

Comment: @ivan : no buddy. I am not able to solve this issue.

Comment: I'm the developer of cool flashlight and i'm facing the same problem with galaxy ace did you solve this problem?

Comment: @Pedro Rainho : not yet.. :(.. i dont find any stuffs related to this on internet..

Comment: No solution yet. Anyone has an answer ?

Answer (score 10):

I will soon released a new version of my app to support to galaxy ace.

You can download here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=droid.pr.coolflashlightfree

In order to solve your problem you should do this:

```
this._camera = Camera.open();     
this._camera.startPreview();
this._camera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {
public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
}
});

Parameters params = this._camera.getParameters();
params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
this._camera.setParameters(params);

params = this._camera.getParameters();
params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
this._camera.setParameters(params);
```

don't worry about FLASH_MODE_OFF because this will keep the light on, strange but it's true

to turn off the led just release the camera

Comment: can you please provide the logcat ?

Comment: no :( I didn't tried it on my phone, but on the phone of a friend of mine :( If i will have the chance i will surely post the logcat.

Comment: I've tested on a galaxy ace and it worked. In my app there is a debug screen. If you press volume key down you will enter in that debug screen. If you check use auto focus, then press initialize, the press on then press off imididatly after on you will see that the led stays on. To turn off the led just press release.

Comment: The exception was my fault, i solved it. I tried on the Galaxy of of my colleague, but the flashlight didn't turn on. This is my code, maybe i forgot something? http://pastebin.com/VFg1eVKF

Comment: I see your problem. Add a small delay between FLASH_MODE_ON and FLASH_MODE_OFF. Setting both at the same time, can causes the led to stay off.

Comment: @Pedro Rainho :- do you have any idea how can i change the Flashlight intensity on non rooted devices?

Comment: I am facing the same issues... Flash light stays for a while and it offs automatically. Have anyone found any solution for this, please post it here.