# turn on flashlight programmatically on motorola fire xt

Tags: android, motorola, led, flashlight, xt

I have tried several code that I found on other stackoverflow posting [turn in off camera led flash light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939816/turn-on-off-camera-led-flash-light-in-samsung-galaxy-ace-2-2-1-galaxy-tab),
[use camera flashlight in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503480/use-camera-flashlight-in-android), code.google.com/p/droidled ,and code.google.com/p/torch but I still cannot turn on led flash on my motorola fire xt.

I also try several flashlight application from android market, but no one can turn on the flashlight.

but when I try the default camera application or [camera 360] from android market, the flashlight will be turn on automatically when I press shoot camera button (flashlight setting must be enable first)

can anybody guide me how to  turn on the flashlight programmatically? Thanks

Comment: Have you found a way ?