# How to turn off Flash light of Camera through intents in Android Programatically?

Tags: android, android-camera

How to turn off Flash light of Camera through intents in Android Programatically?

I use the below code for activating Camera application and then taking the picture and get back to my application.

```
String packageName = takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager).getPackageName();
if (mPhotoFileUri != null)
      getActivity().grantUriPermission(packageName, mPhotoFileUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mPhotoFileUri);

startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

I want to turn off Camera flash when its open by default.How its possible?

Suggestions will be appreciated:-)

Answer (score 0):

to turn on/off the phone camera led or flashlight in Android, you can use following :

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
camera.setParameters(p);
camera.stopPreview();
```

And, not forgot to put following permission on AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

**Edit-1:**

Unfortunately, when using the camera with Intent, the only extra parameter you can set is

```
MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT
```

I'm guess you can't change via `Intent`. Reference from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667094/intent-does-not-set-the-camera-parameters)

Comment: Thanks, Astuter! This code is for custom Camera right? how to pass those parameters to Camera application? I don't want to create my Own Camera in my Application. I want to change the settings of Camera App. Is it possible with this code?

Answer (score 0):

**For this you should do like :**

1) Check whether flash light is available or not ?

2) If yes then Turn Off/On

3) If no then you can do whatever according to your app. needs

**For Checking availability of flash in device:**

You can use the following

```
context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
```

which will return true if a flash is available, false if not.

See [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) for more information.

For turning on/off flashlight :

I googled out and got this about android.permission.FLASHLIGHT. Android manifests' permission looks promising:

```
<!-- Allows access to the flashlight -->
 <permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
             android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
             android:protectionLevel="normal"
             android:label="@string/permlab_flashlight"
             android:description="@string/permdesc_flashlight" />
```

Then make use of Camera and set Camera.Parameters. The main parameter used here is **FLASH_MODE_TORCH.**

eg.

Code Snippet to turn on camera flash light.

```
Camera cam = Camera.open();     
Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
cam.setParameters(p);
cam.startPreview();
```

Code snippet to turn off camera led light.

```
  cam.stopPreview();
  cam.release();
```

**Issues :**

There are also some problems while turning On/Off flashlight. eg. for the devices not having FLASH_MODE_TORCH or even if it has, then flashlight doesnot turn ON etc.

Typically Samsung creates alot of problems.

You can refer about problems in the given below list:

1) [Use camera flashlight in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503480/use-camera-flashlight-in-android)

2) [Turn ON/OFF Camera LED/flash light in Samsung Galaxy Ace 2.2.1 & Galaxy Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939816/turn-on-off-camera-led-flash-light-in-samsung-galaxy-ace-2-2-1-galaxy-tab)

REFERENCE LINK : 
[How to turn on camera flash light programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-to-turn-on-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: Thanks! This code is for custom Camera right? how to pass those parameters to Camera application? I don't want to create my Own Camera in my Application. I want to change the settings of Camera App. Is it possible with this code?