# Android: Turn off flash light with intent

Tags: android, android-intent, camera-flash

I am trying to disable android camera flash by default using intent,
So I have this after googling and research

```
 final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 Parameters p = intent.getParameters();
            p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            intent.stopPreview();
            intent.release();

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
```

My challenge is that intent does not support getParameters in order to use it to turn off the flash camera. How do I tackle this to get the camera parameters using intent to turn off the flash camera.
Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Take a look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251960/how-to-turn-off-flash-light-of-camera-through-intents-in-android-programatically

Comment: I am referring to using intent parameters to trigger off the camera