# What is this error with turning LED to TORCH mode?

Tags: android, camera

I am trying to make my app turn on the led. Whenever I run this code, it crashes. The app closes and gives runtime exception: FATAL Exception, java.lang.nullpointerexception.

```
    Camera cam = Camera.open();     
    cam.getParameters().setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    cam.setParameters(cam.getParameters());
```

Comment: Can you tell to which line is the NullPointerException pointing at? Since here you have only one new object, it seems your `cam` object is `null`. Did you add the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`

Comment: What device/OS version are you running this on?

Comment: android 4.1.2, intel atom (x86)

Comment: I have the permissions: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all your code won't work even if it didn't crash, as you would need something like:

```
Parameters params = cam.getParameters().setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
cam.setParameters(params);
```

However, that won't fix your crash; instead it seems that turning on torch mode is not a simple task, according to posts like this:

- [Use camera flashlight in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503480/use-camera-flashlight-in-android)

Within the answers, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12535804/1270789) seems to cover most of the options.