# android camera led flash light widget not working

Tags: android, flash, camera, widget, light

I am trying to build and led flash light widget but compiler is not showing any error whenever I try to press widget there show widget loading problem 
and android studio does not show any error I am beginner so please help me. Thanks in advance

**Meanifest file**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mateen.flash_light_widget">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <receiver android:name=".NewAppWidget" android:icon="@drawable/example_appwidget_preview" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/new_app_widget_info" />
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="FlashlightWidgetReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="COM_FLASHLIGHT"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

**appwidgetprovider class**

```
   public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                         int[] appWidgetIds) {

        Intent receiver = new Intent(context, FlashlightWidgetReceiver.class);
        receiver.setAction("COM_FLASHLIGHT");
        receiver.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, receiver, 0);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.new_app_widget);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);

    }
}
```

**recevier there is error I think compiler is also not showing any error**

```
   public class FlashlightWidgetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static boolean isLightOn = false;
    private static Camera camera;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);

        if(isLightOn) {
            views.setImageViewResource(R.id.button, R.drawable.example_appwidget_preview);
        } else {
            views.setImageViewResource(R.id.button, R.drawable.example_appwidget_preview);
        }

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context,     NewAppWidget.class),
                views);

        if (isLightOn) {
            if (camera != null) {
                camera.stopPreview();
                camera.release();
                camera = null;
                isLightOn = false;
            }

        } else {
            // Open the default i.e. the first rear facing camera.

            camera = Camera.open();


            if(camera == null) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"noCamera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // Set the torch flash mode

                Camera.Parameters param = camera.getParameters();
                param.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                try {
                    camera.setParameters(param);
                    camera.startPreview();
                    isLightOn = true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"no flash", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**layout file for widget**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/new_app_widget"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/new_app_widget"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/example_appwidget_preview"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard"></appwidget-provider>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

add these permissions to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503480/use-camera-flashlight-in-android

Comment: Sir i tried but its still not working can you sir debug this

Comment: debugging it without log is too hard... did you try to restart your system ? I hope restarting it will help us to get log

Answer (score 0):

i found solution  In order to work, the camera needs a surface to turn on. 
so after camera.startPreview() i wrote this piece of lines

```
surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(0);
 camera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
```

it solved my problem thanks alot :)