# Flash Light not enabling in SAMSUNG Mobile

Tags: android

I am trying to enable the Flash Light in SamSung mobile but its not getting turned on.
here is my code

```
Camera mycam = Camera.open();
Parameters p = mycam.getParameters();
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);// = mycam.getParameters();
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON); 
mycam.setParameters(p);

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
```

And the permissions in manifest is above:

Thanks in Advance
Ranganath.T.M

Comment: Here talk about enable flash in Galaxy Tab, meybe can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017455/how-to-use-camera-flash-led-as-torch-on-a-samsung-galaxy-tab

Comment: what does parameters.getSupportedFlashModes() give you? It's possible that the flash modes aren't supported

Comment: @Slothsberry parameters.getSupportedFlashModes() is giving like off,auto,on

Comment: so you cant even try torch mode. I've got a workaround to try, coming in an answer

Comment: @Slothsberry, i tried with it the result is same the troch not enabled

Answer (score 1):

This is the workaround I use on my Samsung Galaxy Ace for the flashlight. I essentially continuously auto-focus the camera, because the LED only turns on during auto-focus.

```
AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback();
autoFocusCallback.setHandler(handler, message);
//Log.d(TAG, "Requesting auto-focus callback");
camera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallback);


class AutoFocusCallback implements Camera.AutoFocusCallback {

  private Handler autoFocusHandler;
  private int autoFocusMessage;

  void setHandler(Handler autoFocusHandler, int autoFocusMessage) {
    this.autoFocusHandler = autoFocusHandler;
    this.autoFocusMessage = autoFocusMessage;
  }

  public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
      Message message = autoFocusHandler.obtainMessage(autoFocusMessage, success)}
      autoFocusHandler.sendMessage(message)
      autoFocusHandler = null;
  }  
}
```

TORCH_MODE_ON would be preferable, but since it isn't supported, this is the best way I've found, if you simply must have the flashlight.

Comment: Hey can you tell me what your how handler object looks like ?.. What are you doing in that handler object ?

Comment: @Slothsberry i am not able to get how to use this , can you please elaborate it clearly .

Comment: @Slothsberry: please could you explain how the handler object works? Thanks!