# How I do led turn on long time in Samsung Galaxy Ace?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, led

In this moment I am developing a Android App. It's Flashlight, this app have a button for turn on and turn off.
Now, My the problem is led in samsung ace, It's turn on only 5 sec.
But I found in other post the possible solution:
[flash light not enabling in samsung mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009378/flash-light-not-enabling-in-samsung-mobile)

```
AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback();
autoFocusCallback.setHandler(handler, message);
```

but I don't know what is handler object and message object.
thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a nice description of what Handlers are in the [Android SDK | Handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Basically, you give the callback a handler which will handle autoFocus messages when they get placed in the queue by the camera firmware.