# Nexus S Flash torch mode not working

Tags: android, camera, samsung-mobile

I'm using Nexus S Android 2.3 stock version. Whenever I'm trying to set the flash to torch mode:

```
if (camera == null) {
    mCamera = camera = Camera.open();
}
final Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
params.setFlashMode(MODE_TORCH);
camera.setParameters(params);
```

nothing happens, the flash is not working at all. This piece of code works perfectly on nexus one.

I've found this - [How to use camera flash/led as torch on a Samsung Galaxy Tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017455/how-to-use-camera-flash-led-as-torch-on-a-samsung-galaxy-tab) and also this one  - http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=923786 none of them seems to help.

Any idea what am I missing ?

Comment: I can confirm that torch works in nexus S. My app posted here: https://market.android.com/details?id=droid.pr.coolflashlightfree is the prof of that. Also I have a nexus S and works. If you need help get in touch with me and I will sent you a working sample

Comment: Pedro, that sounds great, can you post it here for others to see ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Camera _camera;
protected static final String MODE_TORCH = Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH;
protected static final String MODE_OFF = Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF;

private void initCamera(){
            if(this._camera == null){
            this._camera = Camera.open();
            this._camera.startPreview();
            }
    }

private void releaseCamera(){
        if(this._camera != null)
        {
            this._camera.stopPreview();
            this._camera.release();
        }

        this._camera = null;
    }

private void setCameraParameter(String value){
        if(this._camera != null){
            Camera.Parameters params = this._camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(value);
            this._camera.setParameters(params);
        }
    }

//To turn on just use:
private void turnOn(){
    initCamera();
    setCameraParameter(MODE_TORCH);
}

//to turn off just use:
private void turnOff(){
    setCameraParameter(MODE_OFF);
}

//To release resorces use:
private void releaseResources(){
   releaseCamera();
}
```

This will work on android 2.3. To work on android 2.3 and 4.0.3 you will have to play with surfaceView and surfaceHolder.

Comment: Can you explain more about surfaceView and holder?