# onPeriodicNotification() has the jitters on *some* devices

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

**Why does onPeriodicNotification() behave so erratically?**

**Background**
I'm working on an audio visualizer for Android that samples from the microphone using AudioRecord.read() (16-bit mono).  I've done quite a bit of testing with sample rates and frame periods for setPositionNotificationPeriod().  In the end, I settled on:
**Sample Rate:** 8000
**Frame Period:** Sample Rate * 41 / 1000 = 328
**Buffer Size:** 5 * Sample Rate

The frame period is 41 ms which I chose because I want ~24 frames per second for my visualizer.

I thought that drawing to canvas at this rate would be a problem at first, but after testing on the DroidX and Nexus One, I was getting amazing performance.  I can drop the latency to 20 ms on these devices without buffer-overruns but have no need to.

Once I started testing on the Galaxy S and Nexus S, my performance tanked.  This seemed odd since the Nexus S outperforms both devices by a large degree.  After eliminating drawing and calculations as being the problem, I put timing calls in onPeriodicNotification().  I was able to confirm that the issue is due to this callback being called at willy-nilly time intervals and I do not understand why.

**Creating a Fair Benchmark**
As a fair test, I took all of my audio processing and drawing out of the loop such that all my app does is read audio in a loop and log data in onPeriodicNotification().  I set the frame period to 100 ms and used the following timing code:

```
currentTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
Log.v(TAG, "time since last record update: " + (currentTime - lastTime));
lastTime = currentTime;
```

Finally, I sampled data for 5-minutes on each device.  On the DroidX, I get about what I expect:
**# Points:** 3008
**Min:** 92
**Max:** 105
**Avg:** 100
**StdDev:** 6.64

This seems reasonable and I'm willing to live with this.  On the Galaxy S, I get this:
**# Points:** 3004
**Min:**    0!
**Max:**    274
**Avg:**    100.05
**StdDev:** 126.30?!?

With a StdDev of 126, this means that a subsequent set of timing calls often looks like this [253, 0, 1, 258, 1, 0, 263].

**Conclusion & other misc data**
While performing these tests, I kept an eye on CPU usage.  My process hovers around 2-3% CPU usage with plenty of overhead to work with.  I notice that if I increase the latency between notifications to around 250 ms, the Galaxy S begins behaving as I would expect (the stddev drops to around 6-7).  Unfortunately, 250 ms is far from being a usable latency for audio visualization.

After typing all this I can't help but feel this better belongs in some bug report, but then again this is Samsung we're talking about and we know they have [no internet android bug reporting presence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928267/where-to-report-device-specific-bugs-to-samsung) :(

Alternatives, insights and experience are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately this *seems* to come down to the audio driver.  I've found that Samsung's audio implementation results in incredibly high latency whereas Motorola, HTC and others are sufficiently low enough that I don't notice.

Low latency audio has been on the [bug list](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3434) for a long time, so perhaps this isn't surprising.  If you are doing realtime audio visualization, prepare to be disappointed on Samsung devices :(