# Can not open Notification Access Settings Screen in Android Oreo (Samsung Galaxy S8)

Tags: android, notifications, samsung-mobile, android-8.0-oreo

When I try to open **Notification Access** Settings page on **Samsung Galaxy S8 running Android Oreo**, I'm getting "Unfortunately settings has stopped"

This is the code I'm using:

```
public static final String NOTIFICATION_ACCESS_SERVICE_SETTINGS_PAGE = "android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS";



startActivityForResult(new Intent(AppConstants.NOTIFICATION_ACCESS_SERVICE_SETTINGS_PAGE), 1108);
```

This is working fine on all other devices except Samsung Galaxy S8.

**Note**: I'm not getting any Log since the crash is not happening in my app.

Comment: add log here more help

Comment: the crash is in device settings. I'm not getting any log since it is not in my application.

Comment: Samsung devices have custom TouchWiz interface, created by Samsung Electronics.(TouchWiz is available only on Samsung devices) As many files are customized, it is not possible to find the exact root cause without complete device software information and they even might need sample application code for which issue is seen. I would suggest you to report them the bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928267/where-to-report-device-specific-bugs-to-samsung

Comment: @ManmeetP Thanks, I'll report it.

Comment: Also please share the response here, it will be helpful to all.

Comment: @ManmeetP I'll surely do it.

Answer (score 1):

Samsung devices have custom `TouchWiz` interface, created by Samsung Electronics.(`TouchWiz` is available only on Samsung devices) 
As many files are customized, it is not possible to find the exact root cause without complete device software information and they even might need sample application code for which issue is seen.
 I would suggest you to report them the bug: [Where to report device-specific bugs to Samsung?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928267/where-to-report-device-specific-bugs-to-samsung)